# How to create composite key in ORM Eloquent Laravel 6.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6.2

I would like create a composite key between two table in my database. I have find how to create that in migration but for Eloquente ORM I have found nothing.

So here is my migration :

```php
Schema::create('passages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_contract');
            $table->integer('month');
            $table->integer('year');
            $table->text('object');
            $table->integer('nbPassage');
            $table->decimal('priceExclTax');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('id_contract')->references('id')->on('contracts');
            $table->primary(['id_contract','mois','annee']);
});
```

So I have try to make in model a belong relationship, but when i try to save my object nothing append, and I don't have anny row in my DataBase. So I think this is the wrong way.

If you have an idea please help me ^^.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Your code looks fine. Please give a specific example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't have composite primary keys with Eloquent. Is there a reason you need it to be a composite primary key rather that just having adding a unique index to the fields?

Comment: An exemple of use of my composite key in my app, or an exemple of code ?

Comment: Yes, I need it because for a contract, I don't want two passage at the same month of the same year

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to achieve this with a unique index?

Comment: I don't know because I need to check to check if the month and year is not already taken by another passage for this contract.


Edit : Maybe I can check that in model but i'm not sure where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per laravel, Eloquent does not support composite primary keys.
You can check this issue on laravel github repository [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355)

If you really want to do this then you can override `setKeysForSaveQuery` of `Model.php` and set up your keys.

> By Default:

```
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{
    $query->where($this->getKeyName(), '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery());

    return $query;
}
```

`$this->getKeyName()` will return the primary key name and
`$this->getKeyForSaveQuery()` will return the value of the key.

**This means that Eloquent always filter with only 1 field.**

This which will be called once you perform a `save` action (`UPDATE and DELETE`) and what it does is that it generates a `WHERE` clause in the SQL.

> for e.g.
> Put this into that model that uses a composite primary key:

```
   protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
    {
        $keys = $this->getKeyName();
        if(!is_array($keys)){
            return parent::setKeysForSaveQuery($query);
        }

        foreach($keys as $keyName){
            $query->where($keyName, '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName));
        }

        return $query;
    }

    
    protected function getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName = null)
    {
        if(is_null($keyName)){
            $keyName = $this->getKeyName();
        }

        if (isset($this->original[$keyName])) {
            return $this->original[$keyName];
        }

        return $this->getAttribute($keyName);
    }
```

If you use the Builder argument type in your setKeysForSaveQuery() definition then you'll also need to add the following to the top of the model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

Comment: Thanks it just work. I don't know why is not implement in laravel, it's so simple to use it.

Comment: @MrSolarius If you have a composite key then every relationship that refers to this table will need to duplicate all columns of the composite key which is usually not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but here's how I handled it using [local scopes queries](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#dynamic-scopes)

1- in your `Model` :

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

  public function scopeComposited(Builder $q, $first_key, $second_key)
  {
    $q->where(["first_key" => $first_key, "second_key" => $second_key]);
  }
```

2- to retrieve a model replace `"Model"` with your `Model name` :

```php
Model::composited(1,2)->first();
```